# Testing authentication on REST endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, testing

I could use some help testing the authentication (using spring authentication) of my spring REST endpoints.
I have defined some endpoints requiring authentication using the following annotation @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()").
This seems to be working, because when I start a webserver and go to the URL I'm asked to authenticate, after which I get the proper results.

I run into trouble with my tests.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestContext.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetMethod() throws Exception {
        mvc
            .perform(get("/a-valid-url")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }

}
```

The TestContext class contains some autowired classes in the controller which are mocked, like this:

```
@Configuration
public class TestContext {

    @Bean
    public ClassToMock autowiredClass() {
        return Mockito.mock(ClassToMock.class);
    }

}
```

When run like this I get the following error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: springSecurityFilterChain cannot be null. Ensure a Bean with the name springSecurityFilterChain implementing Filter is present or inject the Filter to be used.

The only solution I have found thus far to get everything running is by adding a springSecurityFilterChain bean in the TestContext class, like this:

```
@Bean
public Filter springSecurityFilterChain() {
    return Mockito.mock(Filter.class);
}
```

However then I always get a Status = 200, even when I use an URL that is not defined in the controller.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated!

**Edit:** Some of the configuration of the project.

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The project has another project as a dependency which contains the TokenContext and AuthenticationStatelessContext configuration XML files.

TokenContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd" >

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.auth.service" resource-pattern="TokenServiceImpl.class"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.auth.service" resource-pattern="ActorRolServiceImpl.class"/>
</beans>
```

The AuthenticationStatelessContext.xml defines the following spring beans: DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler, PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider and UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper.

**Update:**
Created a class named TestContext2:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({
    "classpath:**/AuthenticationStatelessContext.xml",
    "classpath:**/TokenContext.xml"})
public class TestContext2 {

}
```

And added that class to the test

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestContext.class, TestContext2.class})
```

This because spring doesn't allow loading of classes and xml files at the same time in the @ContextConfiguration annotation.

When I try to run the test I still get the following error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: springSecurityFilterChain cannot be null.

PS: The used springframework version is 4.1.3 and the spring-security version is 4.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong to mock the Filter interface to inject a springSecurityFilterChain bean.

What you want is to inject a filter chain with atleast one authentication filter, e.g. UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
CasAuthenticationFilter
BasicAuthenticationFilter. 
Read [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html) spring security filter chain guide to understand which filters to inject for your purpose.

Right now mockito is setting a filter on the springSecurityFilterChain that allows all urls and does not provide the intended filtering behaviour.

The fix could be as easy as including a  referrence to the correct app context along with TestContext on the Test class, depends on how you have defined the context for the rest of the application. I suspect a filter chain bean may be available for auto wiring as well.

**Update:**

Tell spring to load the TokenContext and AuthenticationStatelessContext here:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestContext.class)
```

Remove any code to define security filter chain bean in TestContext

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.
I was under the impression that mocking the filter was wrong, but it was the only way I had gotten the tests running. I also tried defining DelegatingFilterProxy as the springSecurityFilterChain bean, but that gave me a StackOverflowError.

I tried adding several filters to the TestContext class based on the link you gave but I had to keep adding more classes and set up different things so after a while I gave up.

I am leaving the testing of the authentication for later and will focus on other parts of the project for now.

Comment: @Peter because you said that everything runs fine when you run it as a web app, i am pretty confident you don't have to painfully setup the filterChain bean. There should be something in the spring context of your web app that can be simply injected from your test code as well. It might be a bit more help to have a look at your web app context.

Comment: Could you give me an indication of what I should be looking for? I have updated the question with some configuration files.

Comment: Updated my answer to indicate possible fix, please check

Comment: Search your code base for the term "springSecurityFilterChain", you are looking for any context files that defines this bean. Add that context file as well.

Comment: Using the file search of Eclipse it only finds the springSecurityFilterChain from the web.xml. I don't remember seeing a springSecurityFilterChain bean being defined. Does it have to be defined? The application seems to run fine without it. Or do I only need it for the test?

Comment: I was wrong in saying "bean definition". Your web.xml already uses a delegating security filter which means somewhere out there there will be filter bean being setter injected into the delegating filter bean i.e. "springSecurityFilterChain". I suspect spring is not able to see your web.xml while building the mock MVC within the setup() method (@Before). The reason could because of how your projects are setup and the class path dependency between them. Does your test project refer  your main project (wherever the web.xml is) for build dependency?

Comment: At some point I also suspected that the web.xml file was not used, so I tried including it using the ImportResource and ContextConfiguration annotations. The tests are in the same project as the web.xml and the controller classes defining the endpoints that I want to test. Only the security configuration xml files are in a separate project.